# Iphone App Development on Eclipse IDE?

Tags: iphone, windows, eclipse

Is there any possible to develop the Iphone App using Eclipse IDE in Windows? Please note Windows platform has any possibility to the Iphone Development? Any Idea?

EDIT:
How about this [Cygwin TOOL](http://www.cygwin.com/) and [this Blog](http://pjtrix.com/iphone/articles/eclipse-cdt/os-eclipse-iphone-cdt-pdf.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, it isn't possible. iPhone (/iPad/OS X) apps can only be made with Xcode on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MobiOne from Genuitec](http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/). It enables development of web apps for the iPhone. True, it's not as having an official SDK based app in the AppStore, but it looks good, free from Apple's shackles and can be developed using Windows/Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I think your stuck!  Apple only supports XCode and I don't think this will change in the future.

Comment: Indeed, isn't gonna change. Just like you can't develop .NET apps natively on OSX.